# Fixed row position under expandable row group

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I am trying to display text on an SSRS report in a fixed position, regardless of the content above it. The problem is the content above may be one to three lines. As the above content fluctuates, so does the beginning of the next row of content. This happens in two places on the report.

In other words, I need two static starting points for dynamic content. I am printing text onto a pre-designed invoice that doesn't contain any customer data. The invoice is just a template (or shell if you will) and I am to position the data to print into spaces provided on that invoice.

Please see attachments. The attachment with two rows in each field is lining up correctly. I have done this intentionally as a basis. As you can see on the other two attachments, with either one or three rows, the content isn't lining up where it should be due to more or less content than my basis.

I have toyed around with cangrow & canshrink but couldn't get the results as desired.

Appreciate the help!

[image: ssrs setup]

[image: two packages]

[image: three packages]

[image: one package]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to need to re-work your table to get working the way you want.

The way I would do it would be to have one table that groups each page data. Use this table to format your data - putting Rectangles in the area for your lines of data. Rectangles can have a set height so they fill your area when there isn't enough data.

Then you'll have to add another tables inside each of the rectangles to display each sections data.

See my example below - the **RED** represents where the **Rectangles** would go and the **BLUE** for **tables**.

I would keep the old table intact and copy and paste it in each rectangle. Then remove all the parts that that section doesn't need and set your rectangle to the correct size.

[image]

Comment: I'll fiddle with this idea, looks like it just might work if I understand correctly. To be clear, all the graphics you see are on the invoice shell. The SSRS data is the "4-play" and "6-play" rows, along with the dollar amounts in the bottom-right corner.

Comment: Yes - that's what I figured. Only the table text and total amounts are in the SSRS report, the rest is already on your invoice.

Comment: This did the trick! Although I feel compelled to explain my troubles for those who might find this post...

Comment: Creating a rectangle doesn't necessarily mean it won't grow. The rectangle will grow depending on the size of the table. However, if one is able to size the rectangle to be the largest its' containing table will grow to, then one can know where to position the next rectangle/table. Which makes me wonder, if I could have just used the idea of additional tables and avoided the rectangles all together?

In other words, I had to compensate space for the largest possible table. Thanks!